# PHP: How to call echo in custom module / extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I am getting through following beginner tutorial about [writing custom extesions in C for PHP](https://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/). This tutorial module hello.so defines a function hello_world that can be echoed from php.

But how can i call echo directly from C code of the module?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use puts/printf?

Comment: printf ("echo %s; \n", str); or printf ("%s", str); ?

Comment: The second One, is there any advantage of using PHPs print function?

Comment: thank you, i need it for simple debugging my extension

Comment: Than I guess it should Work (I've never tried it)

Comment: printf does nothing :(

Comment: Not even in a PHP Log File?

Comment: I'd try `fprintf` to both `stderr` and `stdout` if it seemed quicker to try than a google search would be to conduct.Failing that (stdout should be the output stream, I'd imagine - not suited to debugging) I'd just open a file and print any debugging messages to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `php_printf`. It uses classic printf syntax. [This](https://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/) quick introduction to some of the concepts might prove useful for you.